# How to design database subset classes with EF and ORM's

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, orm

I am building a web service that attaches to a database. I am planning to use EntityFramework ORM for my persistence layer. I have use a database first approach, designing my tables based on how I see the information mostly efficiently organized.

The ORM generates me some data entities in C#, but now I need to send a subset of that object data to my client via the webservice.

Example:
Say I have a User table with:
-Id
-Username
-Company
-Password
-Email
-AdminNotes

And say I want users to be able to request information on other users, but not all information. So in this scenario I would not want to share the Password, or the AdminNotes about the user. Should I create another Class to represent the UserProfile Summary and populate it manually from my ORM entity? Are there any special patterns I should use to populate these objects? Or can I create similar ORM objects that only represent subsets of the data?

Or should I be using various interfaces to represent my data types and simply serialize the interfaces?

I'm hosting my web service with ASP.NET MVC3 and am serializing everything with JSON. Will I experience complications trying to serialize these EF ORM objects into JSON?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in this scenario I would not want to share the Password, or the
> AdminNotes about the user. Should I create another Class to represent
> the UserProfile Summary and populate it manually from my ORM entity?
>
> Are there any special patterns I should use to populate these objects?
> Or can I create similar ORM objects that only represent subsets of the
> data?

**Yes create ViewModels. You may also consider using Bounded Contexts.**
The approach you choose would reflect YOUR preferred data access and layering technique you plan to use. Having Views ie special classes, used for Rest or Web Services and for MVC access is an often used pattern.

> Or should I be using various interfaces to represent my data types and
> simply serialize the interfaces?

Some people do serialize the Data Domain model. Others elect Not to.
Factors such as the use of Proxies influence such decisions.
I personally dont do that often.

> I'm hosting my web service with ASP.NET MVC3 and am serializing
> everything with JSON. Will I experience complications trying to
> serialize these EF ORM objects into JSON?

Yes you can have headaches with serialization if EF proxies are used.
If you create special views over your domain and use one of the many mapping  tools to populate the view or retrieve from the view, then you a less likely to have issues and UI and Service layer can be decoupled.

imagine you have service based directly on Domain class. What happens if the class is modified to reflect a DB change.  ? Hard to shield that impact on consumers.
So yes i would suggest you do a ViewModel approach.

These sort of design / architecture question is one that start very long discussions.
Consider a bit of research to get comfortable with the topic.

Comment: OK so I presume you mean database views, as non-duplicated subset table views of the original table data? If so then yes I can see the benefit, thanks for the suggestion. But then you suggest using "one of the many mapping tools to populate the view or retrieve from the view". What kinds of tools do you mean? like.. just more EF ORM mapped proxy objects? If that is the case then we've handled the subset problem, but now how to handle the serialization problem? Don't those tools just leave us with the same object types?
Thanks! I'll do some research into views

Comment: by mapping toold example i mean something like https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector

Comment: avoid proxies to make serialization easier. Or Use a VIEWMODEL approach.   see context.Configuration for more info on proxies settings